# How to insert a newline character before a word(s) that contains a colon

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, newline

I have a string that is all one line like:

```
Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi Price: $2,200 Gender: Female Nickname: Koko 
Age: 9 Weeks Old Color/Markings: yellow and white Size at Maturity: 
Medium Availability Date: 09/30/2018 Shipping Area: Worldwide Payment 
Method: Money Order/Cashier's Check, Paypal, Credit Cards, Cash
```

And I want the output to be:

```
Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi
Price: $2,200
Gender: Female
Nickname: Koko
```

etc. etc. Basically insert a `\n` before the new category that ends in a colon.

Thanks for the replies in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you need a newline before every word that contains colon? Because there are cases like `Availability Date:`, `Shipping Area:`, adding newline before just a word with colon may not give expected result for these.

Comment: @Austin you are right, is there any way to do it the way I want? Sorry for the confusion, I am still a newbie.

Comment: How would you do it intuitively, as a person rather than a computer? That may help you find the right condition.

Comment: Do you have a list of the attribute names? Having such a list would substantially simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Austin pointed out above, some of the categories are phrases rather than words. There's no simple way to separate something like "yellow and white Size at Maturity" to figure out where the newline should go. So, you need to have an exhaustive list of all possible categories ahead of time. If you can provide that, there are lots of ways to do this. Here's a simple one:

```
s = "Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi Price: $2,200 Gender: Female Nickname: Koko Age: 9 Weeks Old Color Markings: yellow and white Size at Maturity: Medium Availability Date: 09/30/2018 Shipping Area: Worldwide Payment Method: Money Order/Cashier's Check, Paypal, Credit Cards, Cash"

categories = ['Breed', 'Price', 'Gender:', 'Nickname', 'Age', 'Color/Markings',
              'Size at Maturity', 'Availability Date', 'Shipping Area',
              'Payment Method']

for cat in categories:
    s = s.replace(cat + ':', '\n' + cat + ':')

print(s)
```

If possible though, it would be much better to fix whatever is generating this data so that it has appropriate delimiters in the first place.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/X1a4cdm6 Yes the categories will always be the same and I think I like your method the most. Though, when I do it this is what I get. The first string is the original and the second string is the output.

Comment: It is because the for loop erases all the previous replacements and only leaves the last one, the Payment method. How would I fix that? Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't, and works fine for me in python3. `s` gets overwritten by each call to `s.replace` in the loop, and accumulates the changes.

Comment: My solution also inserts an empty first line into the string, so you may want to add an `s = s.lstrip()` after the loop if that matters.

Comment: Also, that `for` is a great candidate to use `reduce` instead. Something like `output_str = reduce(lambda s, cat: s.replace(cat + ':', '\n' + cat + ':'), categories, input_str)`

Comment: You can use regex to replace all categories at once without a loop: `s=re.sub("({}):".format('|'.join(categories)),r'\n\1:', s)`.

Answer (score 1):

How come no one proposed a regex solution? :)

```
import re
txt = '''your text'''
re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'\n\1:', txt).strip()
```

If there are newlines in the original `txt`, you may end up having double newlines in the output. They can be easily removed:

```
re.sub(r'\n\n', r'\n', # Remove double line breaks
       re.sub(r'(\w+):',r'\n\1:',txt).strip())
```

**This solution assumes that there is only one word of interest before the colon.** As a matter of fact, it is probably not possible to decide how to split 'Shipping Area: Worldwide Payment Method: Money'. Is it 'Shipping Area: Worldwide' and 'Payment Method: Money' or 'Shipping Area: Worldwide Payment' and 'Method: Money'?

Comment: "How come no one proposed a regex solution?". The reason is there can be any (`+`) number of words before `:` before which you need a `\n`. See my comment to question.

Comment: @Austin I saw your comment. But did you see the last line of my post?

Comment: Yes, I do see it. I was answering to your specific question: "How come.... " ;) But this one doesn't completely help OP though.

Comment: @Austin So far, _all_ answers make this assumption. I doubt it is possible to answer the question as asked without using NLP of some sort. So, a regex solution is not worse than any other.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to discriminate multiple word categories from the values that proceed them, but assuming you could limit yourself to single word categories, you could use something like this:

```
import sys
data = "Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi Price: $2,200 Gender: Female Nickname: Koko"
words = data.split(' ')
for word in words:
    if word.endswith(':'):
        sys.stdout.write("\n"+word)
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(" "+word)
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Produces output:

```
Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi
Price: $2,200
Gender: Female
Nickname: Koko
```

Comment: Did you read my comment to the question?

Comment: Yep, hence the first sentence.

Comment: You're outputting an extra newline at the beginning

Answer (score -1):

```
kk = 'Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi Price: $2,200 Gender: Female Nickname: Koko Age: 9 Weeks Old Color/Markings: yellow and white Size at Maturity: Medium Availability Date: 09/30/2018 Shipping Area: Worldwide Payment Method: Money Order/Cashier\'s Check, Paypal, Credit Cards, Cash'
kk_a = [ '\n'+k if k.endswith(':') else ' '+k for k in kk.split() ]
print(''.join(kk_a))
```

Hope this help

The result of the above code

```
Breed: Pembroke Welsh Corgi
Price: $2,200
Gender: Female
Nickname: Koko
Age: 9 Weeks Old
Color/Markings: yellow and white Size at
Maturity: Medium Availability
Date: 09/30/2018 Shipping
Area: Worldwide Payment
Method: Money Order/Cashier's Check, Paypal, Credit Cards, Cash
```

Comment: It says kk_a is not defined

Comment: typo.. alreay fixed it

Comment: Did you read my comment to the question?

Comment: Yes, the original question is kind of confusing.

Comment: Your adding an extra newline at the beginning

Comment: yes, only need to add lstrip('\n') at the final string

Answer (score -2):

Split the string into words using `.split()`. Then, loop through each word, and check if the word ends with a colon using `word[-1]`. If it does, then insert the `\n` character at the beginning of the word.

Comment: OP is literally asking how to do this. This is a restatement of the problem in the imperative, not an answer. Kind of like doing "just do it"

Comment: OP does not mention anything about knowing the `.split()` method or accessing the last character of the word. Perhaps I could have specified the "insert the `\n` character" part better, but that is an easy Google search, and I don't find it helpful just to write the answer for them. Learning how to be self-sufficient, in addition to asking for help, is the most beneficial.